# Error when performing schema changes in DSE 5.0

Tags: datastax-enterprise

I am trying to get my head around using graphs for the first time - and as you can imagine, I am having a fair bit of trial and error. 
Subsequently, I am doing a lot of;

- Create Schema
- find a mistake / modelling error
- delete schena
- rinse and repeat

All of which is completely fine: But for the fact that I seem to constantly be getting the following error;

Schema migration interrupted. The migration operation will continue in the background.

Now if I get this error when doing a schema.clear(), then, it actually doesn't continue in the background at all - it is lying!

I have to rerun the command and sometimes, several times to get the schema deleted.

And if that isn't annoying enough - I might end up with the following, too.

Script evaluation exceeded the configured threshold for the request: [149a3432-b1b3-45b7-8e68-d21c0325d877 - schema.clear()]

I have a single DC, two racks, with 2 nodes each - as a training cluster.
I am using DSE 5.0.1
I am using the GossipingPropertyFileSnitch - snitch
(I also have the rack properties file, too, for the above snitch type.

And I also ensure that I have run;

:remote config timeout max

in the gremlin-console, too...

So I am not really sure how it can complain about timing out and since this is all on my local PC in Virtual machines - and is only being used by me - I don't understand how something is interrupting the command I just asked it to complete, either!

Thanks if anyone has any ideas!

-Gavin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With special thanks to Jeremy at DataStax - I have a solution for my time out issue;

I still don't understand why it complained in the first place - in that I was the only person using the cluster - on virtual machines on my own PC.... but nonetheless - I can successfully complete commands in the gremlin console.

The required change is in DSE.YAML
altering the following configuration item to a value higher than the default of 30 seconds. (I set it to 180 sec)

```
realtime_evaluation_timeout: 180 sec
```